# Vertrauen und trauen im Perfekt

Tags: vocabulary

Ich habe gefunden, dass „vertrauen“ und „trauen“ das Gleiche sein können. Und ich habe einen Deutschmuttersprachler gefragt, ob ich „ich vertraue dir“ und „ich traue dir“ sagen kann. Er hat ‚ja‘ gesagt.

Aber wenn ich ihn gefragt habe, ob ich „ich habe dir vertraut“ und „ich habe dir getraut“ sagen kann, er hat mir geantwortet, dass man eher „ich habe dir vertraut“ sagen würde.

Könnte mir jemand erklären, warum im Präsens beides okay aber im Perfekt *vertrauen* besser als *trauen* ist?

Comment: Trau dich ruhig, *getraut* zu benutzen. Es ist nicht falsch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Verb *trauen* hat mehrere Bedeutungen

> Er hat ihm getraut. — Er hat ihm vertraut.
>
> Er hat sich getraut. — Er war mutig und hat etwas gemacht, was er zuvor nie gemacht hat.
>
> Der Pfarrer hat das Paar kirchlich getraut. — Er hat das Paar verheiratet.

Man kann diese Fälle zwar anhand des Objektes (Dativ, Akkusativ reflexiv, Akkusativ) auseinanderhalten, manchmal — wie im Fall von *getraut* — klingt das aber ein bisschen seltsam. Wenn man sowieso eine Vorsilbe verwenden muss, kann man doch auch *ver-* nehmen, oder?

Comment: Also,  über den Daumen gepeilt es ist besser, ein Verb mit einer Vorsilbe zu benutzen wenn das Verb ohne Vorsilbe viele Bedeutungen hat?

Comment: Richtig. Es sei denn, man will bewusst vage bleiben, zum Beispiel für einen Witz.